# How to extract string from complex string?

Tags: regex, powershell

My start string is:

```
$grp = DL-Test1-Test2-RW"
```

My goal is to have

```
$grp = "Test1\Test2"
```

So i need to keep string between first and last "-" character. And replace - by \

UPDATED
I tried this:

```
$grp = "DL-test1-test2-RW"
$Descritpion = $grp.Split("-") #Split - to have an array
$Descritpion = $Descritpion.Split($Descritpion[0]) #Cut first element
$Descritpion = $Descritpion.Split($Descritpion[-1]) # Cut last element
#Here replace ?
Write-Host "Description:"$Descritpion
```

Comment: This might be helpful [Use PowerShell to Replace Text in Strings](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming string always has this form and you are interested in the 2nd and 3rd parts:

```
# $grp.Split("x") - split string on character x, creating an array
# $grp.Split("x")[n] - get the nth element of the array
# x,y -join "\" join the array elements x and y into a string, with "\" inbetween
($grp.Split("-")[1],$grp.Split("-")[2]) -join "\"
```

**Edit - For generic number of elements**

```
$($grp.Split("-") | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | Select-Object -Last ($grp.Split("-").count - 2)) -join "\"
```

Multiline:

```
$Descritpion = $grp.Split("-")
$Descritpion = $Descritpion | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
$Descritpion = $Descritpion | Select-Object -Last ($grp.Split("-").count - 2) 
$Descritpion = $Descritpion-join "\"
```

Comment: Thx but my string is not always this form. So i adapted your code but i need your help to replace function. See my post updated

Comment: @Ferfa See update that deals with generic number of elements.

Comment: I using PowerShell 2.0 :( :( :( so SkipLast doesn't exist

Comment: Replace it with `-First ($grp.Split("-").count - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

just do it:

```
$grp = "DL-test1-test2-RW"
$arraygrp=$grp.Split("-")
$arraygrp[1..($arraygrp.Count -2)] -join "\"
```

or this

```
$grp.Substring($grp.IndexOf('-') +1, $grp.LastIndexOf('-')-$grp.IndexOf('-')-1 ).Replace('-', '\')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with regex

```
$grp = "DL-Test1-Test2-RW"
$regex = "-(.*)-(.*)-"
if ($grp -match $regex){ 
    $Matches[1] + "\" + $Matches[2]
}
```

If your string can have more groups between start and end, try this

```
$grp = "DL-Test1-Test2-Test3-Test4-RW"
$regex = "-(.*-){1,999}(.*)-"
if ($grp -match $regex){ 
    $Matches[1].replace('-','\') + $matches[2]  
}
```